# Circular buffer implementation with variable-sized items

Tags: c, circular-buffer

I need to code a shared buffer (1R thread/1W thread) in C to asynchronously dump binary program output to I/O.
I normally use the classical circular buffer implementation when it comes to write a simple shared buffer, but in this case the size of each item on the buffer is variable and not-known at compile time.
I was wondering what is a possible implementation of a circular buffer with variable-sized items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may think of it as a circular binary stream. That is, instead if adding an element you'll write the data, instead of popping it you'll read it.

Comment: how would you track the size to read ? writing it directly in the write index ?

Comment: you can write to the buffer a `struct { int size_payload; char* payload}`, after reading first `int` you know how much is the payload (variable-sized item)